# How to make CherryPy server spawn more processes (use multiple cpu cores)?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cherrypy

I can't find any documentation on spawning multiple processes for cherrypy web server. Currently I only use multiple threads:

```
...
server = cherrypy._cpserver.Server()
...
server.thread_pool = 30
```

But as threading performance gain in python is limited by GIL I want to spawn more processes so the server will use more cores to execute the wsgi app's code, what is the correct way to do it?

I am also using `systemd` with the following service config:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=...path to the server script...
User=...
StandardOutput=null
Restart=always
```

What should I do?

Comment: Run it a bunch of times?  Or does CherryPy itself know how to fork?

Comment: Cherrypy only does threading. Forking is outside of the scope of the framework you may run it several times.

Comment: Actually you would not gain any performance from forking cherrypy (the most time it is just waiting for stuff which can be done pretty good with threads). You should rather execute time expensive calculations in a separated process.

Comment: @LittleByBlue yes, but isn't wsgi application's python code executed in the same process? If it's processor heavy it can benefit from multiprocessing isn't it? Or am I mistaking somewhere?

Comment: Hi Bob, i can recommend uWSGI (https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as a alternative Wsgi Server for CherryPy. It supports multi process setup and has a monitoring utility called uwsgitop which is quite usefull. Just make sure that you dont share database connection by all processes or similiar multiprocess unsafe data structures because they will break.

Comment: @Bob You are actually right. Iff you cannot use multi-processing inside your wsgi-app it will be faster to for the cherrypy server. However If you do do not have access to the app's code, maybe you should think of a different way to host the app. Cherrypy is not the fastest server around. You might take a look at apache2 with load-balancing. Usually using a finished solution is easier and cheaper.